# How to check if a row exists compared to another value

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure how to go about this in PHP & MySQL;

But basically, I just want to check to see if a row exists in a table, and if it does, return a error, example:

```
$exists = MYSQL CODE TO CHECK HOW MANY ROWS INCLUDE BADGE_ID
if($exists >= 1)
{
$errors[] = "Exists.";
}
```

Something like that, because I'm coding a small shop script and I want it to check to make sure that they don't already have the `badge_id`. Structure of the db is `user_id` and `badge_id` (`user_id = 1`, `badge_id = 1`; for an example)

Comment: try [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Mysql
$res = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY");
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
   $errors[] = "Exists.";
}

//PDO
$query = $db->prepare("YOUR QUERY");
$ret = $query->execute();
if($ret && $query->rowCount() > 0) {
   $errors[] = "Exists.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for this query as

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT *  from table WHERE userid = 1 AND badgeid = 1");
```

and in php

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){

// whatever you want if match found 

}else{

echo "No match Found".

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE userid = 1 AND badgeid = 1 LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_result($result, 0) > 0)
{
   echo 'exist';
}
else
{
   echo 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table_name` WHERE `user_id` = '1' AND `badge_id` = '1' "
$exists = mysql_query($sql) ; 
if(mysql_num_rows($exists) >= 1) {
      $errors[] = "Exists.";
}else {
   // doesn't exists.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead of the old mysql_query() functions for they are deprecated since PHP 5.5.

For a simple query:

```
$slcBadge = $con->query('SELECT badge_id FROM badges');
if ($slcBadge->rowCount() > 0) {
  $errors[] = 'Exists.';
}
```

Or if you want to fetch all rows from a single user:

```
$sqlBadge = 'SELECT id_badge FROM badges WHERE id_user = :idUser';
$slcBadge = $con->prepare($sqlBadge);
$slcBadge->bindParam(':idUser', $idUser, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$slcBadge->execute();
if ($slcBadge->rowCount() > 0) {
  $errors[] = 'Exists.';
}
```

Notice that in the second piece of code I used `prepare()` and `execute()` rather than `query()`. This is to protect you query from [SQL injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php). By using prepare() you fix the construct of your query so if a user enters a query string as a value, it will not be executed. You only need to prepare a query if a user can enter a value which will be used in your query, otherwise query() will do just fine. Check out the injection link for more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of PHP is important:

- `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of **5.4**, and
- Removed as of **5.5**

It is advised to either implement [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [Mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli)

> mysql:
> This extension is now deprecated, and deprecation warnings will be generated when connections are established to databases via mysql_connect(), mysql_pconnect(), or through implicit connection: use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL instead
> Dropped support for LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE handlers when using libmysql. Known for stability problems
> Added support for SHA256 authentication available with MySQL 5.6.6+

For reference please see [the changelog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.0)

### Structuring your Query

First of all I'm assuming you are indexing your fields correctly [refer to this article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18922/how-should-i-use-indexes-with-mysql/18923#18923) I posted on Stack Exchange.

Second of all you need to consider efficiency depending on the volume of this table:  doing a `SELECT *` is bad practice when you *only* need to count the records - mysql will cache row counts and make your `SELECT Count(*)` much faster. with indexes this is furthermore efficient.

I would simply consider something along the line of this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=DATABASE';
$db = new PDO($dsn, 'username', 'password', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
));
```

> NOTE:
> where host=127.0.0.1 if your user has been granted access via localhost then you need this to state localhost - or grant the user privileges to 127.0.0.1

> NOTE:
> with SET NAMES there is also a bug with the PDO driver from 5.3 (I believe) whereby an attacker can inject nullbytes and backspace bytes to remove slashing to then inject the query.

##Quick example:

```
// WARNING: you still need to correctly sanitize your user input!
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE user_id = ? AND badge_id = ?');
$query->execute(array((int) $userId, (int) $badgeId));

$total = $query->fetchAll();
```